# Angular Material navbar - can't see labels

Tags: angular-material, angular9

Here is my code for navbar:

```
<nav mat-tab-nav-bar>
    <a mat-tab-link
      *ngFor="let link of navLinks"
      [routerLink]="link.link"
      routerLinkActive #rla="routerLinkActive"
      [active]="rla.isActive">
    </a>
</nav>
```

And component:

```
export class SettingsComponent implements OnInit {
  navLinks: any[];
  activeLinkIndex = -1;
  constructor(private router: Router) {
    this.navLinks = [
        {
            label: 'First',
            link: 'syspref',
            index: 0
        }, {
            label: 'Second',
            link: 'userpref',
            index: 1
        }
    ];
}
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.router.events.subscribe((res) => {
        this.activeLinkIndex = this.navLinks.indexOf(this.navLinks.find(tab => tab.link === '.' + this.router.url));
    });
  }
}
```

It works fine except that I dont see labels. Any idea why?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Found it. I was missing {{link.label}}:

```
<nav mat-tab-nav-bar>
    <a mat-tab-link
      *ngFor="let link of navLinks"
      [routerLink]="link.link"
      routerLinkActive #rla="routerLinkActive"
      [active]="rla.isActive">{{link.label}}
    </a>
</nav>
```

Comment: However, when I refresh the page I do get ink-bar shown properly, but the font for the selected label after refresh is not bold. Any idea about that?